# Adding Custom/New Source Types and Fields to Microsoft Word (2019) Bibliography

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography, microsoft-word-2019

I am currently adapting some MS Word Bibliography Styles for standards I use the most because those available for me are "decades" outdated (I also consider creating one from scratch). However, I have noticed that a style using "Thesis" as Type of Source no longer appear at the list to pick, so I guess it was either gone or a custom source type (the style in question is dated from 2009). I barely remember about some files used in the past to create custom types in the style, required by some additional styles, but as far as I checked the files no longer exist.

Anyway, my problem is: the built-in types are far away from the types I need to conform to some standards. Also, the available fields in the built-in types are also way too limited.

Is there any way to add custom ones (, currently)?

Comment: Just as an observation, could the “files used in the past” be the “BibWord” styles by Yves Dhondt? The original site (codeplex) for that material has gone, but The material seems to be on github  (various repositories, but perhaps https://github.com/ydhondt/BibWord is actually Yves Dhondt’s version. There is a lot more description of how the Bibliograpghy stuff fits together in ther than in MS’s documentation but I am not sure you will find clear and definitive answers to your question in there.

Comment: Ohhh, no. I mean, I am using the styles by Yves Dhondt, but I am not talking about the styles. Besides the styles themselves, in older versions of MS Word there were files for the types of fields in the Bibliography form (BibForm, or something like that, I'm not sure about the name). The styles by Yves Dhondt required those files to be added in the past. However, the Thesis type is still listed in the styles by Yves, and yet it shows blank on MS Word, and that's one of the issues I'm facing.